# Rails polymorphic link for nested index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, polymorphic-associations

I have been trying to find this one link for hours now. I have a polymorphic association where both collections & assortments have designs.

Collection model

```
has_many :designs, :as => :targetable
```

Assortment model

```
has_many :designs, :as => :targetable
```

Design model

```
belongs_to :targetable, :polymorphic => true
```

In order to link to the design's 'show' action, the proper polymorphic path would be:

```
link_to polymorphic_path([@targetable, @design])
```

But I can't figure out how to link to the design's 'index' page to show all the designs associated with it's respective targetable object.

Does anyone know the appropriate link to get there??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was finally able to find the answer.

```
polymorphic_path([@targetable, Design])
```

Instead of using a variable as the second object in the polymorphic path, you are supposed to use the model name. This path links to

```
targetable/:targetable_id/designs
```

Maybe this will help someone for future use.

Comment: This is gold! Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, much appreciated.